# событие change на input срабатывает дважды

Tags: javascript, input

Добрый день!
Собственно, проблема в том, что событие change срабатывает дважды при изменении в Input и textarea.код - codepen.io/tokamame/pen/aWrMPM?editors=1011

Comment: Если я всё правильно понял, то он у Вас 2 раза не срабатывает, там в `validateData()` 2 вывода просто.

Comment: спасибо, действительно))

Answer (score 0):

У Вас в коде, а именно в функции-обработчике `validateData()` имеется 2 вызова `console.log()` в связи с этим при единственном срабатывании события, вывод происходит дважды.